# Convert SVG to PDF in python

Tags: python, svg

I am trying to convert an SVG file to PDF in python using the `svglib` and `reportlab` packages. Here is the SVG file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Here is the code I am using to convert (got this from `svglib` webpage).

```
>>> from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
>>> from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF
>>> drawing = svg2rlg("file.svg")
>>> renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "file.pdf")
```

The code runs fine without any error or exception but the `file.pdf` thus generated is a blank file. I mean that when I open this PDF file I see nothing but only white background page with nothing on it.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Don't post here just because you're banned on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make that last line:

```
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "file.pdf", autoSize=0)
```

you will get a nice blue circle on your page. The normal parameter value for  `autoSize` is `1` which results in the PDF being the same size as the drawing.

The problem is with your svg file having no size parameters. You can e.g. change the `svg` openining tag to:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="1000px" width="1000px">
```

to get a similar (visible) result without using `autoSize=0`